# Unable to use ternary operator to conditionally assign `istream &`?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

I have a constructor that accepts a `std::istream &` and checks it before assigning one of the members (a `std::istream &`). For example:

```
class Stream
{
    public:
    Stream(std::istream &is) : s_ {is.good() ? is : throw std::runtime_error {"Invalid input stream\n"}} 
        {}

    private:
    std::istream &s_;
};
```

The compiler complains that the constructor for `std::basic_istream(const basic_istream &)` is deleted (understandably, since you can't copy streams). But, I don't see where any copying is being done here? It must be within the ternary operator, because

```
Stream(std::istream &is) : s {is} {}
```

with no checking works fine. Where is the `std::istream` attempting to be copied? And how can I fix this?

Comment: The compiler is unable to determine the common type.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the issue lies with the `throw`, not the ternary operator.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it should be, though -- a `throw` expression is `void` and there's specific wording for `?:` to handle it.

Comment: Add helper method which takes `istream&` and returns `istream&`, inside you can check `good` call, if fails throw exception. `s_{testMethod(is)}`.

Comment: @rafix07 Would that mean my constructor would have to catch that exception and throw it as well? (e. g.) if the caller wanted to handle it?

Comment: Definitely looks like a gcc bug.

Comment: @DavidTran no, your constructor does not need to catch it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [GCC bug 64372](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64372).

From cppreference on the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator), we learn that if one operands of the conditional operator is a throw-expression, "[t]he result of the conditional operator has the type and the value category of the other expression." Thus, your use of the conditional operator should result in a type of `std::istream&`, but [GCC thinks it's `std::istream`](https://godbolt.org/z/2wEtD1).

---

To work around this GCC bug, use a helper function:

```
class Stream
{
    public:
    Stream(std::istream &is) : s_ {validated_stream(is)} 
        {}

    private:
    std::istream &s_;

    static std::istream &validated_stream(std::istream &is) {
        if (!is.good()) throw std::runtime_error {"Invalid input stream\n"};
        return is;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But the bug is from 2014? Why hasn’t it been fixed yet?

Comment: @DavidTran I'm as surprised as you are. I guess the compiler devs have a lot on their plate, and not many people use this aspect of the conditional operator.

Comment: At least GCC 9.0 is known to work. Still, that was a long dry stretch.

Comment: @Deduplicator It was marked as working in GCC 9.0, but note [Jonathan Wakely's comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64372#c12); it may not be fixed (indeed, the godbolt link I posted shows that—at least this instance of it—is still broken: https://godbolt.org/z/2wEtD1)